# Google drive option won't show up in my File Manager

Tags: nautilus, email, cloud, google-drive

I followed this [Tutorial](https://vitux.com/how-to-access-your-google-drive-account-in-ubuntu/), so that i can use Google Drive directly from my File Manager (Nautilus) But As per the tutorial Step 3

> **Step 3: Mount Google Drive in Ubuntu File Manager**
> Open your Ubuntu File Manager and you will be able to see your Google account listed in the left panel as follows:

I can't see my Email/Gmail ID in my File Manager

It Looks Like This:

[image]

I tried look in `+ Other Locations` Tab But I can't see my Email/Gmail There Too!, it looks like this:

[image]

---

My System Details:

[image]

Edit:

After Following [sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio](https://askubuntu.com/users/226614/)'s Answer

I got this error `gio: google-drive://<your gmail user>@gmail.com/: Location is not mountable` when i executed this command:

```bsh
gio mount google-drive://<your gmail user>@gmail.com/
```

Where `<your gmail user>` was my gmail username

And output of the command `gio mount -l` is

```bsh
Drive(0): TOSHIBA DT01ACA100
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(0): Windows
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(1): hp PLDS DVDRW  DU8AESH
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(2): Generic- SD/MMC/MS PRO
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
```

Output of command `dpkg -l | grep gvfs`

```bsh
ii  gvfs:amd64                                    1.44.1-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - GIO module
ii  gvfs-bin                                      1.44.1-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - deprecated command-line tools
ii  gvfs-common                                   1.44.1-1ubuntu1                                  all          userspace virtual filesystem - common data files
ii  gvfs-daemons                                  1.44.1-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - servers
ii  gvfs-fuse                                     1.44.1-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - fuse server
ii  gvfs-libs:amd64                               1.44.1-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - private libraries
```

Comment: You may have missed something in Steps 1 and steps 2. No way for us to know.

Comment: no I followed everything same as the tutorial

Comment: If you are interested, I am pretty sure that goofle drive Has linux versions of the desktop drive app. Never used the Linuxx version, but I would imagine it is the same as the windows version, which adds your drive folders to the file explorer. That is the windows version of what you're trying to do here. Ill grab a link.

Comment: thanks, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mount the remote location with [`gio`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gio.1.html)

```
$ gio mount google-drive://<your gmail user>@gmail.com/
```

Please report what you get, both when mounting and then in Nautilus (make sure the file manager you are using is Nautilus!).

Also post the output of

```
$ gio mount -l
```

As of now, I wouldn't know the reason why it does not show.

**EDIT**: You might be missing package `gvfs-backends`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with your answer's output

Comment: @COMRADEDEV - 
1) Would you mind posting what I asked on Sep 21?
2) Please post the output of `dpkg -l | grep gvfs`.
3) Updating the kernel (5.8.0 is somewhat old) might help.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: It was working fine for me until today. I used the Software Update manager to update stuff today and apparently it got rid of gvfs-backends, so gdrive didn't mount properly. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Open your settings and go into "Online Accounts" and check if you can see your google account there. If not then probably you have to sign in again.
[Make sure Files option is on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDggv.png)

Probably, you will be able to see your account in File Explorer.

Comment: Yea, my google account is showing, up there and files option is checked there